# Casperjs and jquery-ui tabs "Loading..."

Tags: jquery-ui, casperjs

I'm using casperjs to get all jquery ui tabs on a page and clicking each one. The problem is that the tabs load dynamically and never seem to switch away from the "Loading..." state. I've tried using the casper `wait()` function and even the `waitWhileSelector(`) function but neither seems to work:

```
function getActiveTab () {
    var active_tab = $('#tabs>ul').find('li.ui-tabs-selected').text();
    console.log("Active tab: " + active_tab);
    return active_tab;
}

function clickTabs (tabs) {
    this.each(tabs, function(casper, tab_name, i){
        var child_number = i + 1;
        var tab_selector = "#tabs>ul>li:nth-child(" + child_number + ")>a";
        console.log(tab_selector);
        // this.thenClick(tab_selector).waitWhileSelector('#tabs>ul>li.ui-state-processing', function(){
        this.thenClick(tab_selector, function(){
            var this_tab = this.evaluate(getActiveTab);
        });
    });
}
```

It seems to work for the first tab (because it's the one loaded on page load) but all the rest return "Loading":

```
------ snip passed tests ------
#tabs>ul>li:nth-child(1)>a
#tabs>ul>li:nth-child(2)>a
#tabs>ul>li:nth-child(3)>a
#tabs>ul>li:nth-child(4)>a
#tabs>ul>li:nth-child(5)>a
#tabs>ul>li:nth-child(6)>a
#tabs>ul>li:nth-child(7)>a
#tabs>ul>li:nth-child(8)>a
#tabs>ul>li:nth-child(9)>a
remote message caught: Active tab: Host Allocation
Page Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#disk_pools_table').dataTable')
remote message caught: Active tab: Loadingâ¦
Page Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#vvol_groups_table').dataTable')
remote message caught: Active tab: Loadingâ¦
Page Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#arrayCablesTable').dataTable')
remote message caught: Active tab: Loadingâ¦
remote message caught: Active tab: Loadingâ¦
Page Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#fa_information_table').dataTable')
Page Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#zoning_table').dataTable')
remote message caught: Active tab: Loadingâ¦
Page Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#pool_mismatch_table').dataTable')
remote message caught: Active tab: Loadingâ¦
Page Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#other_information_table').dataTable')
remote message caught: Active tab: Loadingâ¦
Page Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#arrayIPs').dataTable')
remote message caught: Active tab: Loadingâ¦
FAIL 12 tests executed in NaNs, 11 passed, 1 failed.
```

When I use waitWhileSelector it times out after the first click. Most of the tabs dynamically load a script tag with a dataTables object and it would seem that either the table object never loads or the datatables library isn't loading? Do I have to inject that library into the evaluate method, or should the  tag in the page pull it in anyway?

I'd appreciate any help to isolate what's happening in this test.

Answer (score 1):

Need to include the `.js` files of datatables in the `casperjs` option: `clientScripts.`